# Typescript with importsNotUsedAsValues ignores skipLibCheck

Tags: typescript, tsc

In my tsconfig I have

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // ...
    "importsNotUsedAsValues": "error",
    "skipLibCheck": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.tsx", "src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules/**"
  ],

  "files": ["src/typings.d.ts"]
}
```

tsc --version gives 4.9.4

but on check I still have an error

```
This import is never used as a value and must use 'import type' because 'importsNotUsedAsValues' is set to 'error'.

3 import { QueryClient, type QueryKey } from '@tanstack/react-query';
```

from some dependency in node_modules

Any ideas?

Comment: in my case I solved it with providing my package as js file (it was ts before)